# Event Listeners in If statements in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a (maybe strange) Question for you experienced ActionScript gurus out there:
Logically maybe I am missing something but the situation is as follows: I have buttons nested on different frames of a MovieClip and on the attached class of the MovieClip I have an if statement that adds an Event Listener for the button nested on the appropriate frame; However when I run the code it seems that flash is executing the code in order regardless if the condition for running said code is true or not. I was just curious if there's a particular way to handle this sort of condition in a better way?

```
public function Die1() {
    // constructor code
trace("Roll 1 D1 is:", MainGame.valueRoll1);

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 1){
    gotoAndStop(1);
    die1Sd1_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side1process);
}

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 2){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    die1Sd2_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side2process);
}

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 3){
    gotoAndStop(3);
    die1Sd3_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side3process);
}

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 4){
    gotoAndStop(4);
    die1Sd4_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side4process);
}

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 5){
    gotoAndStop(5);
    die1Sd5_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side5process);
}

if (MainGame.valueRoll1 == 6){
    gotoAndStop(6);
    die1Sd6_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Side6process);
}
}
```

Thanks Ahead of time for anyone who replies to this post, I suppose all the syntax knowledge in the world cannot help with program logic...

Comment: As an aside - you can't `gotoAndStop` and then immediately refer to objects on the given frame like that - you have to actually wait for the frame to be constructed first via [`Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#FRAME_CONSTRUCTED).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that, Isn't google handy?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better use a single event listener on the entire die instead of using a lot of listeners that depend on the die's current frame. Like this:

```
function Die() {
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,processDie);
}
// instead of that entire 'if'! 
// Also, this approach will allow you making more dies without spawning classes
function processDie(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch (currentFrame) {
        case 1: side1Process(); break;
        case 2: side2Process(); break;
        case 3: side3Process(); break;
        case 4: side4Process(); break;
        case 5: side5Process(); break;
        case 6: side6Process(); break;
    }
}
```

And in your `MainGame` you do like this:

```
var dice:Array=[];
public function MainGame {
    for (var i:int=0;i<maxDice;i++) {
        var die:Die=new Die();
// make a new die. It'll automatically have an event listener attached
        die.x=i*50;
        die.y=20; // place somewhere
        addChild(die);
        dice.push(die);
    }
    // rest of code follows
}
```

Then, when you have to roll your dice, you do like this:

```
for (var i:int=0;i<dice.length;i++) 
    if (mayIRollTheDie(i)) // provide a correct condition here
        dice[i].gotoAndStop(1+Math.floor(Math.random()*6));
```

Then your dice will change frames according to the roll of 1-6. Their `currentFrame` properties will reflect the roll, so you could easily gather them. And you will no longer need listening to `Event.FRAME_CONSTRUCTED`, because everything is now detached from current frame's objects.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought to do this, it makes ALOT of sense! In my case I'm making a sort of "Poker dice" game and I was curious if It would be more complex code-wise to make each die into a single Array. This does however give me an EXCELLENT jump off point! Thank you so much for your insight! ~Cheers!